# Troubles with creating jQuery animation sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute an animation sequence on progress bars:

```
function animateProgress() {
    var params  = [{from: 50, to: 100}, {from: 0, to: 100}, {from: 0, to: 50}];
    animateProgressStep(params, 0);
}

function animateProgressStep(params, i) {
    $(".progress").width(params[i].from).animate({width: params[i].to}, {
        duration: 2000, 
        complete: function() {
            if(i + 1 < params.length) {
                animateProgressStep(params, i + 1);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

This works if there is a single bar on the page, but if there are many, it breaks on the second iteration because `complete` callback is called as many times as there are progress bar elements on the page.

What would be a solution?

Can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/TythE/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting animation sequence for each element, I feel it is the cleanest and easiest solution:

```
function animateProgress() {
    var params  = [{from: 50, to: 100}, {from: 0, to: 100}, {from: 0, to: 50}];
    $(".progress-overlay").each(function(){
        animateProgressStep($(this), params, 0);
    });
}

function animateProgressStep(el, params, i) {
    el.width(params[i].from).animate({width: params[i].to}, {
        duration: 2000, 
        complete: function() {
            if(i + 1 < params.length) {
                animateProgressStep(el, params, i + 1);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand you, you can add a `finished` property to each param so that it always continues to the next one only once:

```
function animateProgress() {
    var params  = [{from: 50, to: 100}, {from: 0, to: 100}, {from: 0, to: 50}];
    animateProgressStep(params, 0);
}

function animateProgressStep(params, i) {
    $(".progress").width(params[i].from).animate({width: params[i].to}, {
        duration: 2000, 
        complete: function() {
            if(i + 1 < params.length && !params[i].finished) {
                params[i].finished = true;
                animateProgressStep(params, i + 1);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This might work, but I am afraid it would be a racing condition if those `complete` callbacks are running in parallel.

Comment: @serg: I don't think so because JavaScript is single threaded. As soon as it's set `true`, other `complete`s will not do anything.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work very well. It works only for the first element: http://jsfiddle.net/TythE/1/

Comment: @serg: I didn't expect that. Using `setTimeout` works but I'm not entirely sure why yet. http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/TythE/2/

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly:

The `animate` method is operating on all the elements that have the class `progress`. Instead of selecting only on the class, why don't you use an ID?

```
function animateProgressStep(id, params, i) {
    $("#" + id).width(params[i].from).animate({width: params[i].to}, {
        duration: 2000, 
        complete: function() {
            if(i + 1 < params.length) {
                animateProgressStep(id, params, i + 1);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Because that's what I am trying to do - animate many progressbars at once.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want them all to show the same progress?